# HTTP Client with NIO2

Tags: java, http, networking, nio, java-7

Have someone familiar with HTTP Client that based on JDK7 and NIO2,
Implementation that use: AsynchronousSocketChannel

I am looking for implementation that based on NIO2 and can scale out unlimited, thousands of HTTP requests concurrently.

**NOTES:**

1. please do not suggest me an implementation that based on NIO1 like Apache::AsyncHTTPClient and    JBOSS::Netty framework
2. Please do not suggest me a solution that based on distribute solution, I am looking for one client that can handle all the HTTP requests efficiently.

THANKS!

Comment: why do you insist on nio2?  if netty or grizzly can meet your requirements, why not use one of them?

Comment: There is no reason why you need AsynchronousSocketChannel to scale out to thousands of concurrent requests. There is no reason why you even need NIO(1) for that actually, java.net does that perfectly well. So what *is* your reason?

Comment: @irobson Your response doesn't answer the question is is rather rude. The author asked for a Java solution using NIO2 on JDK7. Node.js is a javascript server running on top of the V8 js engine from Google. Furthermore, Node.js performs roughly half as well as NIO2 (AIO) http://www.olympum.com/java/java-aio-vs-nodejs/.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend checking out [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client). It was written by the guy that wrote Grizzy for Sun and now works for Sonatype.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are mistaken in your assumption that you *must* use NIO2 to scale up.  Please listen!

NIO2 is the non-blocking version of Java's IO.  This means it's easier to write high performance io in NIO2 because you need not start and manage threads, because most of your threads are just going to be waiting on IO.  Multi-threaded programming is tricky, so anything to make it easier is a feature, hence NIO2.

However, as a library *user* how hard the library was to write isn't your concern.  Modern JVMs can handle a *lot* of threads and the old io API should be powerful when used by skilled programmers.  Since you are a user of the library, I suggest that you just find the fastest library.

HTTPClient from Apache is a very popular library.  I suggest you get in contact with the experts on that and ask them your performance questions.  I'm not an expert in this area, so I'm not telling you HTTPClient is the best, I'm just saying not to count it out yet and that talking to the HTTPClient people would be a good place to start.

Good Luck

Comment: NIO(1) in JDK 1.4 was already the non-blocking version of java.net. NIO2 in JDK 1.7 contains *asynchronous* I/O as well.

Comment: I didn't even know there were two versions of NIO.  Someone edited my answer a little.  But like I said the old Java IO (not NIO) is also quality software, it just has a blocking design.